# Voz a texto casi resuelto, con android y python

Tags: android, python

Tengo corriendo un script Python en un móvil con Android.

Reconoce la voz en forma continua y lo envía por socket a una Raspberry y de ahí a los sensores y todo lo demás.

Cuando no interpreta una palabra pide intentarlo otra vez pero hay que darle partida en forma manual.

Uso el Reconocimiento de voz de Google que traen los equipos con Android.

¿Sabe alguien cómo hacer que no se detenga la detección cuando hay un error?

```
import android
dr=android.Android()
sp=dr.recognizeSpeech('>',None,None)
txt=sp[1]
print txt
```

En esta parte se bloquea cuando hay un error de codificación.

Para usarlo offline, descargue el idioma al móvil.
Así lo estoy implementando por ahora:

```
import sl4a
import time, socket
dr=sl4a.Android()
svr=('192.168.18.7',55565)
while True:
   fra=dr.recognizeSpeech('#',None,None)
   try:
      txt=fra.result.lower()
   except:
      txt='err'
   print (txt)
   s=socket.create_connection(svr)
   s.sendall(txt.encode('utf-8')
   s.close()
   time.sleep(3)
   if 'fin'in txt:
      break
```

De esta manera envio las ordenes de voz a raspberry, aunque sirve para cualquier cosa.
El problema es que no es 100% continua la deteccion.
Ayuda ...

Comment: Tengo un PC manejando la domotica de mi casa, sensores de movimiento, apertura, luces, comunicación al celular etc..